# File downloading but without any contents in it

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, download

I have a text file called output.txt that will generated inside D:/MPI. I have to download this file but the file which is getting downloaded is completely blank and does not have any contents. I want to download the file output.txt which is in the folder D:/MPI. Here is my code of JSP

```
<%
String filePath = "D://MPI//output.txt";
String fileName = "outputs";
FileInputStream fileToDownload = new FileInputStream(filePath);
ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
response.setContentLength(fileToDownload.available());
int c;
while((c=fileToDownload.read()) != -1){
out.write(c);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
fileToDownload.close();
%>
```

Kindly guide me

Comment: Why are you using *Scriplet*. Just move this code to Servlet instead of using JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are developing a web application and file will be served from the web server. So try to make the path relative to the context of the application instead of using absolute path.

Try with [ServletContext#getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) method that returns a String containing the real path for a given virtual path.

Put the `output.txt` file inside the war/webapp folder of the project and try below code:

```
String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("output.txt");
```

---

**Note:** Always try to avoid the *Scriplet* instead use [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html). Move this code in Servlet from the JSP in this case. Treat the JSP for UI and always keep the business and database logic in the Servlet.